# Javassist with Tomcat web application to add loggers to specific zone

Tags: java, web, tomcat8, javassist

I am trying to modify a class during run time of a web application hosted on tomcat.
I tried going trough all the materials available, but I am unable to find an exact solution for the same.
It breaks on ClassPool initialization.
My motive is to have a agent ready, for whenever added to the jvm will alter few class's methods to add loggers. Please let me know if anyone has any solution.

Comment: Please post your code and stack traces.

Comment: The problem seems to arise with multiple boot loaders, it works fine with a standalone application.
While starting tomcat server
below is the stacktrace 
"Executing premain.........
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Comment: "FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.NotFoundException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 7 more"

Comment: I solved this issue, 
 JarURLConnection connection = (JarURLConnection) RQAgent.class.getResource("RQAgent.class").openConnection();
   inst.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch(connection.getJarFile());
in my agent